# If $a$ and $b$ are elements of a finite field $k$, then $f(x)$ must have a root in $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

Following is the whole question:

If $a$ and $b$ are elements of a finite field $k$, then $f(x)$ must have a root in $k$, where $f(x)=(x^{3}+ax+b)(x^{2}+4a^{3}+27b^{2})$.

I have finished most of the proof, but I was stuck in the near end.

First, assume $char(k)=p>0 \neq 2,3$. Suppose $f(x)$ has no root in $k$.

Then, the discriminant of $g(x)=(x^{3}+ax+b)$ is not a square in $k$. This is true if and only if the Galois group of $g$ over k is $S_{3}$. However, this cannot be true since any Galois extension over a finite field is cyclic.

However, I am now stuck in the case where $char(k)=2$ or $3$. I am learning algebra following Lang's book, so in the argument of the discriminant of the cubic extensions and the Galois group, he assumes that $char(k)$ is not $2$ or $3$. Therefore, I don't know how to argue in the next steps.

Any thoughts and explanations are really appreciated!!

**EDIT 1**

Let me modify my proof a little bit, since my original proof is not totally correct. Note that even after the modification, I still have the original question, since in this proof I used $char(k)\neq 2$ or $3$

$f(x)$ has must have a root in $k$ implies, either $g(x)=x^{3}+ax+b$ has a root or $h(x)=x^{2}+4a^{3}+27b^{2}$ or they have a common root.

My proof above eliminate the chance that they have a common root.

So now, suppose $g(x)$ is irreducible over $k=\mathbb{F_{p^{n}}}$.

As $g(x)$ is irreducible over $k$ of degree 3, the Galois group of $g(x)$ over $k$ has order 3 or 6 since the Galois group if a subgroup of $S_{3}$. However, since every Galois extension over a finite field is cyclic, it must be of order 3, which implies that the Galois group is $A_{3}$.

This implies that the discriminant of $g(x)$ is a square in $k$, but notice that the discriminant of $g(x)$ is $-4a^{3}-27b^{2}$, which is the solution of $h(x)=0$. Since it is a square, $h(x)=0$ which implies $x^{2}=-4a^{3}-27b^{2}$ has a solution.

Thus, there must be always solution for $f(x)$,

However, I still do not know how to deal with the case where $char(k)=2$ or $3$.

**EDIT 2**

Now, with my quasi's answer and my edited proof, this whole proof is complete!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $\text{char}(k)=2$, then $x=b$ is a root of $x^{2}+4a^{3}+27b^{2}$.

Next, suppose $\text{char}(k)=3$.

If the function $g:k\to k$ given by $g(x)=x^3+ax+b$ is injective, then since $k$ is finite, $g$ would also be surjective, hence $g(x)$ would equal $0$, for some $x\in k$.

Suppose then that $g$ is not injective.

Thus, for some $u,v\in k$, with $u\ne v$, we have $g(u)=g(v)$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;&g(u)=g(v)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^3+au+b=v^3+av+b\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^3-v^3=-a(u-v)\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^2+uv+v^2 = -a\\[4pt]
\implies\;&u^2-2uv+v^2 = -a\\[4pt]
\implies\;&(u-v)^2= -a\\[4pt]
\end{align*}
Let $t=u-v$, and let $x=t^3$.
\begin{align*}
\text{Then}\;\;x^{2}+4a^{3}+27b^{2}&=x^{2}+a^{3}\\[4pt]
&=t^6+a^3\\[4pt]
&=(t^2)^3+a^3\\[4pt]
&=(-a)^3+a^3\\[4pt]
&=0
\end{align*}

Comment: WOW! I am sorry for the late reply, I was editing my original proof. Now it is complete with you help!!!